# Find script that performs actions for print requests - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

In page: Admin->Sales->Orders

There is a script in the block, which contains the following passage:

**sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject.setItems**

I've been trying to find it in the archives of magento, can no success, could someone help me?

Comment: yout are probably looking at js/mage/adminhtml/grid.js.  the method is around line 424

Comment: umm, is not this file, if you go to your page **Admin->Sales->Orders** and check the source code the page current,  find the occurrence **sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject.setItems** , but search it in all the project, nothing. 
Thanks for your attention

Comment: magento dynamically generates some javascript that creates an object called sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject based on the class varienGridMassaction in grid.js.  that's why you don't find sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject in the magento files.  But if you look at the javascript in the view source, you'll see: `var sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject = new varienGridMassaction('sales_order_grid_massaction', sales_order_gridJsObject, '', 'internal_order_ids', 'order_ids');`  which is where sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

it should be different when use different version of Magento.

In Magento v1.9 (CE), it's sales_order_gridJsObject. And you can find varienGrid definition in Magento grid.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    sales_order_gridJsObject = new varienGrid('sales_order_grid', 'http://??.79.6.??1/magento2/index.php/admin/sales_order/grid/key/2bf50108008bb393909de069bfed163d/', 'page', 'sort', 'dir', 'filter');
    sales_order_gridJsObject.useAjax = '1';
            sales_order_gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = openGridRow;
                     var sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject = new varienGridMassaction('sales_order_grid_massaction', sales_order_gridJsObject, '', 'internal_order_ids', 'order_ids');
                     sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject.setItems({}); 
                     sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject.setGridIds('');
                     sales_order_grid_massactionJsObject.errorText = 'Please select items.';        //]]>
</script>
```